# Replace :parameter in IN-statement with functions around it repeated

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace the parameter `:firstname` of the query by multiplying the expression as much as there are elements in the `$firstnames` array.

This is what I've got so far:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 IN(UNHEX(:firstname)) OR IN (UNHEX('foo'))";

$firstnames = array("Jack", "John", "Michael");
$replacement = "";
foreach ($firstnames as $key => $value) {
    $replacement .= "\${1}".$key.",";
}
$replacement = rtrim($replacement,",");

$pattern = "/(:[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)/i";
$query = (preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $query)).",";

echo $query;
```

So far I only replaced the parameter, but not the function around it. There might be several other functions or string concatenations that should also be part of the repeating replacement. There might be some nested parenthesis also. So this would be the pattern to get all the nested parenthesis for the IN-statement:

```
$pattern= "/(\s*IN\s*)(\(((?>[^()]+)|(?2))*\))/i";
```

I just can't find a way to combine the two statements, to properly replace the parameter and the stuff that has been wrapped around it. Also, if there's no parameter in the IN-statement, there should be no replacement. This should be the result:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 IN(UNHEX(:firstname1), UNHEX(:firstname2), UNHEX(:firstname3)) OR IN (UNHEX('foo'))";
```

**UPDATE: Solution!**
In the meantime I stumbled upon several Problems, but finally solved the problem.

It seems not to be possible to get all the stuff by just using a regex. Therefore I decided to go with the `preg_replace_callback` function. In the first step I get the whole IN function, determined by all it's nested parentheses. In the second step I get the parameter an replace it with the desired amount of repetitions.
**The solution below fyi:**

```
$params = array(
    "firstname" => array("Jack", "John", "Michael")
);

$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 IN  (UNHEX(:firstname)) OR col2 IN(UNHEX('foo'))";

function createIN($query, $arrParam) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        "/(\\s*IN\s*(\\((?:(?>[^()]+)|(?2))*\)))/is", 
        function ($matches) use($arrParam) {
            $pattern = "/(\s*IN\s*\()((.*?((['\"`]).*?\5)?)*)(:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(.*)(\))/is";
            preg_match($pattern, $matches[1], $matches2);
            $replacement = $matches[0];
            if(isset($matches2[6])) {
                $replacement = $matches2[1];
                foreach ($arrParam[substr($matches2[6],1)] as $key => $value) {
                    $replacement .= $matches2[2].$matches2[6].$key.$matches2[7].",";
                }
                $replacement = rtrim($replacement,",").$matches2[8];
            }
            return $replacement;
        }, 
        $query
    );
}

echo createIN ($query, $params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the query dynamically, and use prepared statements. A simple way to do this is to add each parameter name to an array and then use [implode()](http://php.net/implode) to convert the array into a comma-separated list of the names. This example should work:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 IN(";

$firstnames = array("Jack", "John", "Michael");
$params = array();
$query_in = array();
foreach ($firstnames as $key => $value) {
    //$params[] = $value;
    //$query_in[] = "?";
    // Use this for named parameters:
    $params[":param".$key] = $value;
    $query_in[] = ":param".$key;
}

$query .= implode(",",$query_in);
$query .= ") OR IN (UNHEX('foo'))";
/** @var PDO $pdo */
$stm = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stm->execute($params);

echo $stm->queryString;
```

Comment: It is intended to use prepared statements. The query but could be anything. The query given in the question is just an example. The solution you suggest here is what I'm already using. But i really wanted to use named parameters to make the code more dynamic an readable. If I use the ? params have to be in the right order. This can be very hard to manage and read inside the code.

Comment: @BenjaminDudler
Replace with this then:
        $params[":".$key] = $value;
        $query_in[] = ":".$key;

Comment: I wrote a wrapper class for the PDO functions. If the user submits a query containing `IN(:parameter)` he only needs to pass the parameter as an array to the wrapper class witch will then translate the statement. It will make the code to be written by the user much easier to read an manage. Your solution is what I've been using so far.

Answer (score 1):

if you really looking for a regex solution:

Changed for comment:

Finally:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 IN(UNHEX(CONCAT(UPPER(CONCAT(:firstname, 'baz')), 'bar', 'quz'))) OR col1 IN (UNHEX('foo'))";

$firstnames = array("Jack", "John", "Michael");

$pattern = '/((\w+\()+:firstname)(\D+)*((\))+)/i';
if (preg_match($pattern, $query, $matches) === 1) {
    $match = substr(preg_replace('/(IN\s*\()/i', '', $matches[0]), 0 ,-1);
    $function = substr($match, 0, strpos($match, ':firstname'));
    $brackets = substr($match, strpos($match, ':firstname')+10);
    foreach ($firstnames as $key => $value) {
        isset($replacement) ? $replacement .= ",{$function}:firstname{$key}{$brackets}" : $replacement = "{$function}:firstname{$key}{$brackets}";
    }
}

$query = str_replace($match, $replacement, $query);

echo $query;

$query = SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 IN(UNHEX(CONCAT(UPPER(CONCAT(:firstname0, 'baz')), 'bar', 'quz')),UNHEX(CONCAT(UPPER(CONCAT(:firstname1, 'baz')), 'bar', 'quz')),UNHEX(CONCAT(UPPER(CONCAT(:firstname2, 'baz')), 'bar', 'quz'))) OR col1 IN (UNHEX('foo'))
```

Hope that helps.

---

Really finally:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 IN(UNHEX(CONCAT('paz', UPPER(CONCAT('qaz', 'qar', :firstname, 'baz')), 'bar', 'quz'))) OR col1 IN(UNHEX(CONCAT('paz', UPPER(CONCAT('qaz', 'qar', :lastname, 'baz')), 'bar', 'quz'))) OR col1 IN (UNHEX('foo'))";

$firstnames = array("Jack", "John", "Michael");
$parameters = array(':firstname', ':street', ':lastname');
$pattern = '/((\w+\()+)(\D+)(:[a-z])(\D+)*((\))+)/i';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $query, $matches) >= 1) {
    $tempMatches = array();
    if (is_array($matches[0])) {
        foreach ($matches[0] as $moreMatches) {
            $tempMatches[] = $moreMatches;
        }
    } else {
        $tempMatches[] = $matches[0];
    }
    foreach ($tempMatches as $myMatches) {
        $match = substr(preg_replace('/(IN\s*\()/i', '', $myMatches), 0 , -1);
        foreach ($parameters as $param) {
            if (strpos($myMatches, $param)) {
                $function = substr($match, 0, strpos($match, $param));
                $brackets = substr($match, strpos($match, $param) + strlen($param));
                foreach ($firstnames as $key => $value) {
                    isset($replacement) ? $replacement .= ",{$function}{$param}{$key}{$brackets}" : $replacement = "{$function}{$param}{$key}{$brackets}";
                }
                $query = str_replace($match, $replacement, $query);
                unset($replacement);
            }
        }
    }
}

echo $query;

output = SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 IN(UNHEX(CONCAT('paz', UPPER(CONCAT('qaz', 'qar', :firstname0, 'baz')), 'bar', 'quz')),UNHEX(CONCAT('paz', UPPER(CONCAT('qaz', 'qar', :firstname1, 'baz')), 'bar', 'quz')),UNHEX(CONCAT('paz', UPPER(CONCAT('qaz', 'qar', :firstname2, 'baz')), 'bar', 'quz'))) OR col1 IN(UNHEX(CONCAT('paz', UPPER(CONCAT('qaz', 'qar', :lastname0, 'baz')), 'bar', 'quz')),UNHEX(CONCAT('paz', UPPER(CONCAT('qaz', 'qar', :lastname1, 'baz')), 'bar', 'quz')),UNHEX(CONCAT('paz', UPPER(CONCAT('qaz', 'qar', :lastname2, 'baz')), 'bar', 'quz'))) OR col1 IN (UNHEX('foo'))
```

Comment: What if the query was like `$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 IN(UNHEX(CONCAT(:firstname, 'bar')) OR col1 IN (UNHEX('foo'))";` There might be also other functions used inside the IN-statement, e.g. UCASE, SUBSTR, etc.

Comment: Thank you, but e.g. CONCAT rarely comes without at least a second parameter. If I used `IN(UNHEX(CONCAT(:firstname, 'bar')))` it won't work.
I guess I need some kind of lookahead in the regex to determine if there is a parameter like `(?<param>:[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)` somewhere inside the IN-statement. If there is, match the whole content of the IN an replace the matches of <param>. But I can't get it running ...

Comment: Didn't like my solution? You miss something?

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is nice so far, we're getting nearer. The Problem is, that e.g. `IN(UPPER(CONCAT('bar', :firstname, 'baz')))` won't work. Basically every valid SQL-code that would work, if I just used a single name (in this example) must be parsable. 
Also the parameter is not always `:firstname` it can be just anything, e.g. `:lastname` or `:street`

Comment: Please see last Edit... I think now you know how it could be solved.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In my solution I also solved the problem if there is a quoted string witch contains an : inside, so that it might not accidentally be misinterpreted as parameter.